# I need to alter my code so that it shows highest to lowest

Tags: sorting, python-3.x

In my code so far I have done it so that the average is shown and the students can be sorted in alphabetical order. However, I need to alter my code so that the results can be stored from highest to lowest but i am struggling with this.

In my text file it looks like this:
name,3,4,5
2name,5,6,7
3name,3,4,5

where each name is different

This is my code so far:

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, marks):
        self.name = name
        self.marks = marks
    def avg_mark(self):
        return sum(self.marks)/len(self.marks)
    def __str__(self):
        return '{0}: {1}, {2}'.format(self.name, self.marks,     self.avg_mark())

def load_grades(filename):
    fd = open(filename, 'r')
    f = {}
    for line in fd:
        split = line.split(',')
        key = split[0]
        marks = [int(n) for n in split[1:]]
        try:
           f[key] += marks
        except KeyError:
            f[key] = marks
    students = []
    for key, values in f.items():
        students.append(Student(key, values[-3:]))
    return students

def sort_by_name(students):
    def get_name(student):
      return student.name
    students = sorted(students, key=get_name)
    return students

def sort_by_avg(students):
    def get_avg(student):
        return student.avg_mark()
    students = sorted(students, key=get_avg)
    return students


again = True

while again:
    class_num =  input ('Which class do you want to view 1,2 or 3?')
    print('please input a, b or c')
    print('a)Alphabeically')
    print('b)average')
    print('c)highest to lowest')
    sort = input ('how would you like to view it:')

    if class_num =="1" and sort =="a":
        students = load_grades('class1.txt')
        students = sort_by_name(students)
    elif class_num =="1" and sort =="b":
        students = load_grades('class1.txt')
        students = sort_by_avg(students)

    for student in students:
        print(student)


    Again=input('Do you want to view another class yes or no?')
    again = (Again=='yes')

print('bye')
```

I want it so that when c is pressed the the numbers are sorted from highest to lowest.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "from highest to lowest". Like, "5,5,5" > "5,5,4" > "5,4,4" > "5,4,3" >"5,3,3" = "4,4,3" > "4,3,3" ?

Comment: so it will sort the numbers for each student highest to lowest and then sort the highest scores for each student from highest to lowest.(If that makes sense)